# Summing an array using PHP

Tags: php, sum

I have an array of data that I'm getting from this form (form.php):

```
<?
   include"connect.php";
   $sql = "select * from tbsatpor ";
   $qry = mysql_query($sql);
   echo"<form name='submit' method='POST' action='proses.php'>";
   $no  = 1;
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
      $nomor  = $no++;
      echo "<input type='text' name='kd_satpor[]' value='$data[kd_satpor]' > 
            <input type='text' name='kd_unor[]' value='$data[kd_unor]' >
            <input type='text' name='buy[]' value=''><br>";
   }
   echo"<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></form>";
?>
```

Here's resultpage.php:

```
<?
  echo "<table border='0' size=100%>
         <tr><td>CODE</td><td>BUY</td><td>UNOR</td><td>TOTAL SUM</td></tr>";
  for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['buy']);$i++){
     $_session[$i] =  $_POST['kd_satpor'][$i];
     $_session[$_POST['buy'][$i]] =  $_POST['buy'][$i];
     $_session[$_POST['kd_unor'][$i]] =  $_POST['kd_unor'][$i];
     $total[i]  =  $_session[$_POST['kd_unor'][$i]] * $_session[$_POST['buy'][$i]];

     if($total[i]!=0){ 
        echo "<tr><td>".$_session[$i]."</td><td>" .$_session[$_POST['buy'][$i]]." X                
              </td><td>".$_session[$_POST['kd_unor'][$i]]."=</td><td>".$total[i]."</td>
              <td></tr>";
     }
  } 
  echo"</table>";
?>
```

The data array looks like this (the output of resultpage.php):

```
CODE   | BUY   | UNOR | SUM
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
024K30 | 10000 | 2    | 20000 | => 10000 x 2 = 20000
024K31 | 2000  | 3    | 6000  | =>  2000 x 3 = 6000
024K32 | 5000  | 3    | 15000 | =>  5000 x 3 = 15000
                        TOTAL?
```

I want to create TOTAL SUM from the array and show the result from that code. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: I'm sorry but that code is an absolute mess. I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: I know you were just told to come here from Meta Stack Overflow, but this is very difficult to understand.

Comment: Okay, I took pity on you and edited because you were directed here. (At least, I tried; I had a hard time understanding your question.) In the future, _please_ read our formatting guidelines in the future. We use a system called Markdown, not HTML. Didn't you notice that none of your `&nbsp;`s were having any effect on your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$finalTotal = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['buy']);$i++)
{
    ...


    $finalTotal += $total[i];
}

echo 'Final Total: ' . $finalTotal;
```

Also, use `$_SESSION` not `$_session` if you intend to use the PHP session and don't forget to run any POST data through `htmlentities()` before you echo it out onto a page.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess as to what you want:

```
<? 
$OverallTotal=0;
echo"<table border='0' size=100%> 
<tr><td>CODE</td><td>BUY</td><td>UNOR</td><td>TOTAL SUM</td></tr>"; 
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['buy']);$i++) 
 { 
 $_session[$i]=$_POST['kd_satpor'][$i]; 
  $_session[$_POST['buy'][$i]]=$_POST['buy'][$i]; 
   $_session[$_POST['kd_unor'][$i]]=$_POST['kd_unor'][$i]; 
   $total[i]=$_session[$_POST['kd_unor'][$i]]*$_session[$_POST['buy'][$i]]; 
   $OverallTotal+=$total[i];

   if($total[i]!=0) 
   {  

echo "<tr><td>".$_session[$i]."</td><td>" .$_session[$_POST['buy'][$i]]." X </td><td>".$_session[$_POST['kd_unor'][$i]]."=</td><td>".$total[i]."</td><td></tr>"; 

} 
}  
echo"</table>"; 

echo $OverallTotal;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Incrementing Operators as below:

```
<?php
$totalSum = 0;
echo"<table border='0' size=100%>
<tr><td>CODE</td><td>BUY</td><td>UNOR</td><td>TOTAL SUM</td></tr>";
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['buy']);$i++)  {
    $_session[$i]=$_POST['kd_satpor'][$i];
    $_session[$_POST['buy'][$i]]=$_POST['buy'][$i];
    $_session[$_POST['kd_unor'][$i]]=$_POST['kd_unor'][$i];
    $total[i]=$_session[$_POST['kd_unor'][$i]]*$_session[$_POST['buy'][$i]];    
    if($total[i]!==0) { 
        $totalSum +=$total[i];
        echo "<tr><td>".$_session[$i]."</td><td>" .$_session[$_POST['buy'][$i]]." X </td><td>".$_session[$_POST['kd_unor'][$i]]."=</td><td>".$total[i]."</td><td></tr>";
    }
}
echo "<tr><td colspan='3' align='right'><b>TOTAL</b></td><td>".$totalSum."</td><td></tr>";
echo"</table>";
?>
```